# Format model's display date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that has a Date property. Currently the dates are displaying both the date and time like `3/12/2012 12:00:00 AM` but I would like them to just be the date like `3/12/2012`. I have attempted to use the DisplayFormat data attribute in several different ways but am not having any success.

```
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")>
Public Property ActivityDate As Date
```

I access the property through the Html helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ActivityDate)
```

Why is this not displaying correctly? Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this format string:

```
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{d}")>
```

The "d" for `DateTime` fields is the short date pattern of dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy depending on your locale.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Comment: @Elliot make sure you are using a lower case "d".  It's case sensitive.

Comment: Ya i literally just copy pasted your line. Interesting enough, now if I submit a form with no input for the date field it gives me an "Incorrect format" error. But existing records are still being displayed with the time at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")>
 Public Property ActivityDate As Date
```

Comment: No luck :( I still see the time.